# Dynamic form in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, if-statement

I am generating the form based on the data from API.

**Form Data:** (Api returns array of object but in my example I have converted it to JSON for better understanding but data is array of object like below)

```
  [
    {
      "id": "formDescription",
      "label": "Form Description",
      "type": { "name": "text" },
      "value": {
        "value": "Use this request for vaccination status",
        "type": {
          "name": "string"
        }
      },
      "properties": { "viewOnly": "true" },
      "typeName": "text"
    },
    {
      "id": "vaccinated",
      "label": "Vaccinated",
      "type": {
        "values": {
          "vaccinated": "Vaccinated",
          "not_vaccinated": "Not Vaccinated"
        },
        "name": "enum"
      },
      "value": {
        "value": null,
        "type": {
          "name": "string"
        }
      },
      "validationConstraints": [],
      "properties": { "groupName": "Letter Details" },
      "typeName": "enum"
    },
    {
      "id": "dose",
      "label": "Dose",
      "type": {
        "values": {
          "dose_one": "Dose One",
          "dose_two": "Dose Two"
        },
        "name": "enum"
      },
      "value": {
        "value": null,
        "type": {
          "name": "string"
        }
      },
      "validationConstraints": [],
      "properties": { "groupName": "Letter Details" },
      "typeName": "enum"
    },
    {
      "id": "reason",
      "label": "Reason",
      "type": { "name": "string" },
      "value": {
        "value": null,
        "type": {
          "name": "string"
        }
      },
      "validationConstraints": [],
      "properties": { "groupName": "Letter Details", "maxlength": "50" },
      "typeName": "string"
    },
    {
      "id": "doseOneDetails",
      "label": "Dose One Details",
      "type": { "name": "textArea" },
      "defaultValue": null,
      "value": {
        "value": null,
        "type": {
          "name": "string"
        }
      },
      "validationConstraints": [
        { "name": "maxlength", "config": "400", "validator": null }
      ],
      "properties": { "groupName": "Letter Details", "maxlength": "400" },
      "typeName": "textArea"
    },
    {
      "id": "doseTwoDetails",
      "label": "Dose Two Details",
      "type": { "name": "textArea" },
      "defaultValue": null,
      "value": {
        "value": null,
        "type": {
          "name": "string"
        }
      },
      "validationConstraints": [
        { "name": "maxlength", "config": "400", "validator": null }
      ],
      "properties": { "groupName": "Letter Details", "maxlength": "400" },
      "typeName": "textArea"
    }
  ]
```

So based on this data I need to generate a form. And generating of form is already working as per the below provided example.

**Requirement:**

*Scenario 1:*

User selects `vaccinated` as an option from first select box, then the select box with data as `Dose One` and `Dose Two` appears. Then if user select any of the dose then he need to add details on that respective dose.

*Scenario 2:* (Working Now)

User selects `Not Vaccinated` as an option from first select box, then the `reason` select box will be displayed.

*Scenario 3:* (Working Now)

User selects `Other` as an option from first select box, then the `moreDetails` text box will be displayed.

**Technical Requirement:**

To achieve this condition checks, I have included multiple **if..else..if** conditions like,

```
  if (Array.isArray(name) && name.length) {
    const [fieldName] = name;
    if (fieldName === "vaccination_status" && value === "vaccinated") {
      setFieldsToHide(["reason", "moreDetails"]);
    } else if (
      fieldName === "vaccination_status" &&
      value === "not_vaccinated"
    ) {
      setFieldsToHide([
        "dose",
        "doseOneDetails",
        "doseTwoDetails",
        "moreDetails"
      ]);
    } else if (fieldName === "vaccination_status" && value === "other") {
      setFieldsToHide([
        "reason",
        "dose",
        "doseOneDetails",
        "doseTwoDetails"
      ]);
    }
  }
```

So for example if my form grows and in the first select box if more options are added then after selecting an option from first select box, the second select/input box gets displayed. If second one is a select box then again based on that the next select/input box gets displayed and goes on.

In the above given example consider vaccination. Once user selects the vaccination, the dose select box gets displayed then after the dose the respective dose details input box gets displayed. (**So one depends on another is the requirement**).

**Working Example:**

[image: Edit antd typescript (forked)]

**How can we remove this multiple `if...else...if` condition check with hard coded values and make it configurable may be by modifying the original data structure or some other way?**

*Kindly please fork the given codesandbox and provide solution which would me much more highly appreciated.*

Comment: Check out https://jsonforms.io/ and see if it fits your needs rather than rolling your own solution. Regardless, I would highly suggest reading about (and utilizing) the JSON schema specification. It supports conditional subschemas and if-else properties, i.e. a field can be conditionally included or excluded depending on other fields or values. https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/conditionals.html#if-then-else

Comment: @jered, Thanks for your reply. I have been instructed to put my own solution to achieve the result **without** including any other extra/third party **library** for this. But I am a beginner in this kind of implementation, so stuck at this point. Any solution that solves the above mentioned issue would help me much.

Comment: JSON Schema is not a good solution for this. I say this as one of the people who runs the JSON Schema project itself. Building dynamic form generation without any third party tools is a challenge, but it can be done. You can use JSON Schema to build your conditional checking system without needing to use it to also generate your forms.

Comment: @Relequestual, Thanks for your reply. Do you have any alternative for this scenario? If possible could you please provide me a apt solution? I am very beginner in this and I have been redirected to JSON schema but now I am coming to know that this is not a solution. So any good solution will really help me to understand better. Thanks .

Comment: Unfortunatly no. This is a compex task and you're asking for it to work inside your existing codebase. If you're not willing to use an existing library, it sounds like you have other requirements which we do not know or you cannot share. I'd go back to whoever asked you to do this and ask for help and clarificiation of requirements.

Comment: "I have been instructed to put my own solution..." -- is this homework? I don't know why else you would not be able to use a third party tool.

Comment: As because we are already using more third party here for this form.. If you can suggest a third party/solution with it then it would be helpful.. I have been instructed to put my own solution as because it is possible without any third party.

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking for. You say the code works, what is the issue? Maintainability? Do you have an example for how the form can grow? If you can edit the underlying JSON data, can you include field configurations there, i.e. hidden if field X has any of value Y? This seems to be what note implies, and is effectively what your `onFieldsChange` logic is trying to achieve. Instead of encoding every possible scenario why can't the form data structure lend itself to this?

Comment: @DrewReese, Give me 10 mins. I will rephrase entire question with better clarity.

Comment: @DrewReese, Now updated the question with more information with change in data value for better understanding. Requirement is how can I get rid of checking for multiple `if...else...if` condition (with hard coded values). It is okay that we can ask the backend team to modify the data of api.. So I am in the need of help to generate dynamic form by eliminating these multiple condition check with hard coded values.

Comment: IDK, it seems the dynamic part you need is completely dependent on the form data driving it.... pushing it there seems the logical choice to me.

Comment: @DrewReese, Thanks for that info bro. But for that we as a frontend team needs to provide the structure that we need. So could you help me in modifying the data structure accordingly?

Comment: I see your goal but I am confused with your json object. Usually when we build a dynamic UI, there should be a hierarchy or contain some sort of relationship between object, like what object/component lives under what other object/component Example, your doses objects/component should live under vaccinated object/component. But your JSON just has list of object to render but no solid relationships between them.

Comment: @GaneshBudhathoki, We only have form data now as like given data structure. Thing is that we can modify the data structure and form the dynamic form as per the requirement and then we can provide the modified data structure to Backend team and they can modify and provide me updated end point in real app.. But here the requirement is that we can modify the given data structure alone as per our requirement and make the dynamic form as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add a "hiddenField" key which contains all keys need to hide whenever the field value have changed.

```
[
 ...
 {
    "hiddenField": {
    "vaccinated": ["reason", "moreDetails"],
    "not_vaccinated": [
      "dose",
      "doseOneDetails",
      "doseTwoDetails",
      "moreDetails"
    ],
    "other": ["reason", "dose", "doseOneDetails", "doseTwoDetails"]
    }
 }
...
]
```

And then we change your entire if..else code to this

```
  if (Array.isArray(name) && name.length) {
    const [fieldName] = name;
    if (fieldName === "vaccination_status") {
      setFieldsToHide((data[1] as any).hiddenField[value]);
    }
  }
```

[Here is an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-typescript-forked-hx2pb?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: This line `fieldName === "vaccination_status"` contains hard coded value (vaccination_status) which is the first thing I am in the need to ignore.. Also if user select vaccinated, then I need to display dose select box and after selecting any particular dose then the respective dose details input needs to be displayed.. To make it short it here, each input field depends on another and so on which needs to be dynamic..

Comment: OK, I think you just need to replace your if...else code. So you need to check that object has property "hiddenField" to hide fields whenever input changed in order to make it reusable for other input. And if you want to each input fields depends on others, you just need to create "showField" property to show fields with the same technique on "hiddenField"

Answer (score 0):

if you need an "own solution" there are too many ways to achieve it.

may be this little example is useful for you, but you must develop it further.

data:

```
"properties": { "groupName": "Letter Details", "maxlength": "400", "display": {"equals": ["vaccinated", "not_vaccinated", "none", "inherits"]} }
```

and code:

```
if ( typeof Properties.display === "string" )
  setProperty("display",Properties.display);
else if ( typeof Properties.display === "object" )
  if( Properties.display.equals )
    setProperty("display", getFormValue(Properties.display.equals[0]) ===  Properties.display.equals[1] ? Properties.display.equals[2] : Properties.display.equals[3]
  else if( Properties.display.less_than )
     ...
```

Also, each property can be automatized : if ( typeof Properties.[counter] ) ...

Comment: Do you have any working example like in codesandbox?

Answer (score 0):

in demo.tsx you can try (you can rename and change argument for better)

```
import React, { useState, useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { GeneratedForm } from "./GenerateForm/GenerateForm";
import { FieldData } from "rc-field-form/lib/interface";
const jsonData = require("./data.json");
const loadData = () => JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(jsonData));

const objHide = {
  vaccinated: ["reason", "moreDetails"],
  not_vaccinated: ["dose", "doseOneDetails", "doseTwoDetails", "moreDetails"],
  other: ["dose", "doseOneDetails", "doseTwoDetails", "reason"]
};

function Demo() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const [fieldsToHide, setFieldsToHide] = useState<string[]>([
    "reason",
    "dose",
    "doseOneDetails",
    "doseTwoDetails",
    "moreDetails"
  ]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data.length === 0) {
      setData(loadData().data);
    }
  }, [data]);

  const onFieldsChange = useCallback(
    (changedFields: FieldData[], allFields: FieldData[]) => {
      const valueSelected = changedFields[0].value;
      const hideArray = objHide[valueSelected];
      setFieldsToHide(hideArray);
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <GeneratedForm
      formData={data}
      onFieldsChange={onFieldsChange}
      fieldsToHide={fieldsToHide}
    />
  );
}

export default Demo;
```

Comment: If we select vaccinated as an option then all the inputs related to vaccination are displayed. Requirement is once the vaccination status is selected, the dose value need to be selected and if it is selected then the respective dose detail input will be displayed.. This is how the flow will go on.